# My Top 10 actions chart always shows "No data to display"

Tags: recaptcha-v3

[image: recaptcha v3 analytics charts]
On my recaptcha v3 admin page, some charts always shows "No data to display".

Why is that and How do can I fix it?

This is my script...

```
        grecaptcha.ready(function() {
            grecaptcha.execute('site_key', {action: 'login'}).then(function(token) {
                document.getElementById('g_recaptcha_response').value = token;
            });
        });
```

thank you.

Comment: This could use some editing to improve the grammar of your question.